# What component can i use for displaying tabular data fastly

Tags: slickgrid

We already used jqgrid for displaying data.But it took more time to dispaly data(we have more than 5000 data).
We tried with slick grid.But faced the same issue there.So slick grid is more faster than jqgrid .If so then why slickgrid also taking time.

Please help me to proceed my research.

Thanks
Jins

**Latest Comments**

```
 var columns = [{name:'Personnel',field:'accommodationId',id:'orientation'},   
                {name:'Employer', field:'itemSystemID', id:'itemSystemID', width:110} ] 

 var gridData=somVO;
 grid = new Slick.Grid("#testGrid",gridData, columns);
```

**Benchmarks**:
- Query took 28 sec
- action class takes 32 sec or more

Comment: SlickGrid supports [large data sets](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html). "Slow" is relative to perception. Add the code that you have tried so far along with some benchmarks. If both data display methodologies were slow it's most likely due to how they were used (source code) which is missing from the post.

Comment: @Origineil We return 3000 datas from server side as json format.So while loading data its taking around 1 mint.When we use pagination ,this issue is not happening.But we want a solution to populate all the data without using pagination.So I tried slick grid.But thats not reflecting in application.It took same time to load the screen.Actullay i dont know how to proceed my analysis.If I put static data,it took around 1 mint to load the screen

Comment: @Origineil var columns = [{name:'Personnel',field:'accommodationId',id:'orientation'},
{name:'Employer',f ield:'itemSystemID', :'itemSystemID',width:110} ]
 var gridData=somVO;      
grid = new Slick.Grid("#testGrid",gridData, columns); For time being i used few columns.

Comment: @as per your suggestion added comments in the end of post

Comment: That amount of time to process such a small data sample is not good. Post the source code for the query and the class in question. Without code to analyze it is difficult to identify potential issues.

Comment: I have a grid which I load data from SQL Server and send it through JSON, that is all done in 8sec for 45k rows with about 10 columns...That comes from my intranet, so it's local network which is of course quite fast. So unless you provide more code we can't help you.. but most probably your problem is not on frontend (SlickGrid) but instead is backend (from SQL to JSON)...You're probably trying to load your data through regular internet, you should at least compress your JSON data to get better performance. Your problem is not the SlickGrid like I said, it's most probably your config

Comment: @Origineil This is not small data.Here i showed only one column.Around 1200 datas are fetching from query .I will check the server side and will post the code.